# delegate does not work in c#

Tags: c#, delegates

Does anyone know why control would never get to the delegate although it is invoked? It doesn't get there regardless if I'm step-debugging or not.

```
public void UpdateClock()
{
    //control never gets here 
}

delegate void UpdateClockDelegate();    

private void MT_TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    { 
        //control gets here, but does not invoke, apparently
        Invoke(new UpdateClockDelegate(UpdateClock)); 
    }
}
```

I based this solution according to the explanation in the following 
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/507f5d4b-d33e-40e0-8802-05fe46519658/)

Comment: Is your timer enabled?

Comment: Should be if the debugger gets there. (Tick Event gets fired)

Comment: Could the UI be blocked? When you call `Invoke()`, behind the scenes it posts a message to the application's message queue which must be processed by the control's message pump. If the UI is currently blocked, the message won't be processed and the method won't be called.

Comment: You need to set `Timer.Enabled` to true (or call `Start()`) if you want the timer to raise the event. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` and `InvokeRequired` are normally used to ensure that a function is executed on the UI-thread. It normally Invokes itself, not another function.

Your code could become like this:

```
public void UpdateClock()
{
    ...
}

private void MT_TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    { 
        Invoke(new Action<object, ElapsedEventArgs>(TimerTick), source, e); 
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateClock();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I agree with Scorpi0 to use the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, which will always fire the event on the UI-thread automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

- `System.Timers.Timer` : the event is called `Elapsed`, it takes a `ElapsedEventArgs`
- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` : the event is called `Tick`, it takes a `EventArgs`

As I can see, the signature

```
MT_TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

ring an alarm.
It should be either

```
MT_TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

or

```
MT_TimerTick(object source, EventArgs e)
```

Check you are using the good one, and your event are subscribe.

- For `System.Timers.Timer`

```
 MT_Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MT_Timer_Elapsed);
 MT_Timer.Start();
 void MT_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) { }
```

- For `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

```
MT_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(MT_Timer_Tick);
MT_Timer.Start();
void MT_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it can help you...

```
public void UpdateClock()
{
    this.MT_TimerTickCompleted += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //When MT_TimerTick occur, do something
    };
}

delegate void UpdateClockDelegate();    

private void MT_TimerTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    { 
        MT_TimerTickNotify(object, e); 
    }
}

public event EventHandler MT_TimerTickCompleted;
private void MT_TimerTickNotify(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MT_TimerTickCompleted != null)
        MT_TimerTickCompleted(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers. My current theory on why this doesn't work is as follows: I have Parallel.Invoke going. This makes the threads go into MT_TimerTick, but the main UI thread (to which UpdateClock() belongs to) is halted until parallel.invoke ends. I should replace parallel.invoke with background workers.